# Get SPContext in Web Method of Provider hosted app of MVC Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, spcontext, mvc, webmethod

I am developing a Provider hosted app of MVC type for SharePoint Online.
I am trying to get the SharePoint Context  in a Web Method in  provider Hosted app of Type MVC application. I am able to get the context in the Index method.

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            User spUser = null;
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    // objClientContext = clientContext;
                    spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
                    clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

But i am not able to get the same context in the Web Method.

```
  [WebMethod]
        public JsonResult GetSiteWithContext()
        {
            User spUser = null;
            SiteCollection objsiteColl = new SiteCollection();
            try
            {
                var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
                using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                {
                    spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
                    clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    objsiteColl.Title = spUser.Title;
                    //  return Json((new { objsiteColl }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(objsiteColl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I am getting the  error  `object reference not set to an instance of an object` at the   line  `using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())`

If i write a Web method without using the context it working fine.

```
 [WebMethod]
        public JsonResult GetSiteWithoutContext()
        {
            Name objName = new Name();
            objName.SiteName = "DEMO";
            return Json(objName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //  return Json((new { objName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get the SharePoint Context in Web Methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the WebMethod.  Any MVC controller methods can be called via AJAX.
so remove WebMethod from your method.

`public JsonResult GetSiteWithoutContext()
{
     -- your logic
     return Json(objName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }`

then use ajax call from your Javascript method